# How to convert .reg files to PowerShell set-itemproperty commands automatically?

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-registry, conversion

I am a tinkerer who does many registry hacks and I hate having to click many `.reg` files one by one; how do I convert `.reg` files to PowerShell `Set-ItemProperty` commands automatically?

- I found a site that does so [[Registry to PowerShell Converter](http://reg2ps.azurewebsites.net/)], however the output isn't in the format I wanted; I want it to have the exact same syntax as below using `Set-ItemProperty`/`Remove-Item`/`New-Item` and nothing else:

  ```powershell
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications]
  "NoToastApplicationNotification"=dword:00000001
  ```

  - `cmd`:

    ```powershell
    Reg Add "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications" /v "NoToastApplicationNotification" /t REG_DWORD /d 1
    ```
  - `powershell`:

    ```powershell
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications" -Name "NoToastApplicationNotification" -Type DWord -Value 1
    ```
- The command to produce intended result should be:

  ```powershell
  "Set-ItemProperty -Path " + $path + "-Name " + $name + "-Value " + $value
  ```

  - I have created an ASCII table with information found [here](https://www.ascii-code.com/) and uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ypknmkakuC_UvdI_n6vMk4OFOgzmbnfx/view?usp=sharing), managing this [[output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qYXFp1E5cW5B0MS2gwgmNAsybYaM3sAu/view?usp=sharing)]:

    ```powershell
    $ASCII=import-csv ".\desktop\ascii.csv"
    [array]$AsciiTable=0..255 | foreach-object{
      $Decimal=$ASCII[$_].DEC
      $Hexadecimal=$ASCII[$_].HEX
      $Binary=$ASCII[$_].BIN
      $Octonary=$ASCII[$_].OCT
      $Symbol=$ASCII[$_].Symbol
      $Value=[char]$_
      $Description=$ASCII[$_].Description
      $HTMLName=$ASCII[$_].HTMLName
      $HTMLNumber=$ASCII[$_].HTMLNumber
      [pscustomobject]@{Decimal=$Decimal;Hexadecimal=$Hexadecimal;Binary=$Binary;Octonary=$Octonary;Symbol=$Symbol;Value=$Value;Description=$Description;HTMLName=$HTMLName;HTMLNumber=$HTMLNumber}
    }
    $AsciiTable | Export-csv ".\Desktop\AsciiTable.csv"
    ```

Currently I have managed this, which is incomplete, but the idea is to loop through file by `index`, assigning values to variables via regex match, changing type and hivename to ones used in PowerShell:

```powershell
$registry=get-content $regfile

for ($i=0;$i -lt $registry.count;$i++){
  $line=$registry | select-object -index $i
  if ($line -match '\[' -and '\]') {
    $path=$line -replace '\[|\]'
    switch ($path)
    {
      {$path -match "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"}    {$path=$path -replace "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT","HKCR:"}
      {$path -match "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"}    {$path=$path -replace "HKEY_CURRENT_USER","HKCU:"}
      {$path -match "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"}   {$path=$path -replace "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE","HKLM:"}
      {$path -match "HKEY_USERS"}           {$path=$path -replace "HKEY_USERS","HKU:"}
      {$path -match "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG"}  {$path=$path -replace "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG","HKCC:"}
    }
  }
  else {
    $name=($line | select-string -pattern "`"([^`"=]+)`"").matches.value | select-object -first 1
    switch ($line)
  {
  {$line -match}
}
```

---

There are six registry value types [`REG_SZ`, `REG_BINARY`, `REG_DWORD`, `REG_QWORD`, `REG_MULTI_SZ`, `REG_EXPAND_SZ`] and I have seen only one `DWORD` value type in `.reg` files, although I managed to make a registry key containing all types:

- `RegEdit`: 
   [image]
- `.reg`:

  ```powershell
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AarSvc]
  "DependOnService"=hex(7):41,00,75,00,64,00,69,00,6f,00,73,00,72,00,76,00,00,00,\
    00,00
  "Description"="@%SystemRoot%\\system32\\AarSvc.dll,-101"
  "DisplayName"="@%SystemRoot%\\system32\\AarSvc.dll,-100"
  "ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
  "FailureActions"=hex:80,51,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,14,00,00,\
    00,01,00,00,00,10,27,00,00,01,00,00,00,10,27,00,00,01,00,00,00,10,27,00,00,\
    00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
  "ImagePath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
    74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
    00,76,00,63,00,68,00,6f,00,73,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2d,00,\
    6b,00,20,00,41,00,61,00,72,00,53,00,76,00,63,00,47,00,72,00,6f,00,75,00,70,\
    00,20,00,2d,00,70,00,00,00
  "ObjectName"="NT Authority\\LocalService"
  "RequiredPrivileges"=hex(7):53,00,65,00,49,00,6d,00,70,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,6f,\
    00,6e,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,\
    65,00,00,00,00,00
  "ServiceSidType"=dword:00000001
  "Start"=dword:00000003
  "Type"=dword:00000060
  "UserServiceFlags"=dword:00000003
  "New Value #1"=hex(b):00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AarSvc\Parameters]
  "ServiceDll"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,\
    00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,\
    41,00,61,00,72,00,53,00,76,00,63,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
  "ServiceDllUnloadOnStop"=dword:00000001
  "ServiceMain"="ServiceMain"
  ```

How are registry types determined within a `.reg`, as the intended end-result is a text file/string array/PowerShell script that contains the converted commands?

- In a `.reg`, I know values for type `REG_DWORD` is written as `dword`, `REG_SZ` as plain text enclosed in quotes, `REG_QWORD` as `qword` (shown [here](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/84189-convert-reg-files-bat-files.html)), and have already mapped registry types to their corresponding PowerShell properties:

  ```
  REG_SZ        → String
  REG_EXPAND_SZ → ExpandString
  REG_MULTI_SZ  → MultiString
  REG_BINARY    → Binary
  REG_DWORD     → DWord
  REG_QWORD     → QWord
  ```

  With the relations inferred from above:

  ```powershell
  switch ($line)
  {
    {$line -match '"="'}      {$type="string"}
    {$line -match "dword"}    {$type="dword"}
    {$line -match "qword"}    {$type="qword"}
    {$line -match "hex\(2\)"} {$type="expandstring";break}
    {$line -match "hex\(7\)"} {$type="multistring";break}
    {$line -match "hex\(b\)"} {$type="qword";break}
    {$line -match "hex"}      {$type="binary"}
  }
  ```

---

How can I detect and decode the registry hex babbles and are there other ways to write `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, `REG_MULTI_SZ`, and `REG_BINARY` types in a `.reg` (i.e. as `ExpandString`, `MultiString` and `Binary` respectively)?

- Script to parse registry expandable string values to plain text:

  ```powershell
  function parse-expandstring {
    PARAM (
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true)] [System.String]$expandstring
    )

    $AsciiTable=import-csv ".\desktop\AsciiTable.csv"
    [array]$hex=$expandstring -split'[\,\\]' | where {-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_))} | %{$_.trimstart()}
    $hexadecimal=0..($hex.count-1) | where {$_ % 2 -ne 1} | foreach-object {$hex[$_]}
    $text=@()
    foreach ($hexadecima in $hexadecimal) {
      for ($i=0;$i -le 255;$i++) {
        if ($AsciiTable[$i].hexadecimal -eq $hexadecima) {
          $text+=$AsciiTable[$i].value
        }
      }
    }
    $text=$text -join ""
    $text
  }
  ```
- `Function` to parse `REG_QWORD`:

  ```powershell
  function parse-qword {
    PARAM (
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true)] [System.String]$qword
    )
    [array]$qword=$qword -split','
    $qword=for ($i=$qword.count-1;$i -ge 0;$i--) {$qword[$i]}
    $hexvalue=$qword -join ""
    $hexvalue=$hexvalue.trimstart("0")
    $hexvalue
  }
  ```
- `Function` to parse `REG_BINARY`:

  ```powershell
  function parse-binary {
    PARAM (
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true)] [System.String]$binary
    )
    [array]$hex=$binary -split'[,\\]' | where {-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_))} | %{$_.trimstart()}
    $hex=$hex -join ""
      $hex
  }
  ```
- `Function` to parse `REG_MULTI_SZ`:

  ```powershell
  function parse-multistring {
    PARAM (
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true)] [System.String]$multistring
      )

    $AsciiTable=import-csv ".\desktop\AsciiTable.csv"
    [array]$hex=$multistring -split'[\,\\]' | where {-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_))} | %{$_.trimstart()}
    $hexadecimal=0..($hex.count-1) | where {$_ % 2 -ne 1} | foreach-object {$hex[$_]}
    $text=@()
    foreach ($hexadecima in $hexadecimal) {
      for ($i=0;$i -le 255;$i++) {
        if ($AsciiTable[$i].hexadecimal -eq $hexadecima) {
          if ($i -ne 0) {$text+=$AsciiTable[$i].value}
          else {$text+="\0"}
        }
      }
    }
    $text=$text -join ""
    $text
  }
  ```

---

The script is almost complete, having already created `Remove-Item`, `New-Item`, and `Remove-ItemProperty` switch conditions; now, the final piece of the puzzle is to write a regex that matches the values. When this is done, I will post it as an answer here.

- Pseudo code:

  ```powershell
  if $line match [ and ]->$line match [-HKEY -> Remove-Item
  else $registry[$i+1] eq ""->New-Item
  elseif $line match "=-" -> Remove-ItemProperty
  ```
- I created an ASCII hashtable to use as a dictionary:

  ```powershell
  $asciihex=@{}
  0..255 | % {
    $number=$_
    [string]$hex=$number.tostring('x')
    if ($hex.length -eq 1) {$hex='{1}{0}' -f $hex,'0'}
    $char=[char]$number
    $asciihex.add($hex,$char)
    }
  ```

  - To look for a character at a given codepoint:

    ```powershell
    # Change:
      $asciihex.'00'

    # to:
      $asciihex.'ff'
    ```
  - To look for a character at any codepoint:

    ```powershell
    # Don't use $asciihex to print it
      $asciihex.$codepoint
    ```

To grep values from lines, use `-replace $name+$type` to get the value.

Comment: For registry value type determination, please see [RegistryValueKind Enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind).

Comment: For the basics on updating registry values in PS, here is an old article from The Scripting Guy:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/update-or-add-registry-key-value-with-powershell/

Comment: you could also just put all the reg files in a directory, and have a script or function that you call that adds all reg files in that location to the registry. probably much easier and more errorproof

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to avoid, because I want to put all commands in a single .ps1 file, and .reg files can be hard to edit, if it is a .ps1 file with one command each line, editting it would be simpler.

Comment: Does this script do what you want? https://github.com/milesgratz/Convert-Reg/blob/master/Convert-Reg.ps1

Comment: It doesn't do what I intended...

Comment: What I don't really get yet is this part `I want it to have the exact same syntax as below using Set-ItemProperty/Remove-Item/New-Item` - If you convert a .reg to a .ps1, how would you know when you have to remove an Item? It would simply create a .ps1 with a lot of Set-ItemProperty and maybe New-Item, no?

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς Please use correct markdown [e.g. weblinks], also the longer and more in-depth/complex an answer/question becomes, the more important markdown formatting becomes to break it into its constituent sections, which is why I keep editing your answer, but it would be awesome if you could include such formatting when adding additional info. All formatting edits I do in general are from a professional outline point of view, as formatting makes a question/answer far easier to navigate for anyone reading it, which becomes vital the longer and more complex an answer/question becomes.

Comment: To determine when to use Remove-Item, New-Item and Remove-ItemProperty, first check if the line matches a pair of square brackets, if it matches, check if it also matches HKEY, if it matches, then it is a valid path. For valid pathes, first check if it matches [-HKEY, if it does, Remove-Item; If it is valid and doesn't match, first check if the next line is empty, if the next line is empty, New-Item. If none above, store the path in variable. If it matches "([^"=])+"=-, Remove-ItemProperty.

Comment: Ok, I literally did not know that this was possible in a .reg file *blush*. But I read the docs of .reg file standards now. I'll have a go at a script in the evening

Comment: On a second thought, using "New-Item -Path $Path -Force -erroraction silentlycontinue | Out-Null" on every [HKEY line seems to be better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

### ***Final version:***

```
Function reg2ps1 {

    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true)]
        [Alias("FullName")]
        [string]$path,
        $Encoding = "utf8"
    )

    Begin {
        $hive = @{
            "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" = "HKCR:"
            "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" = "HKCU:"
            "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" = "HKLM:"
            "HKEY_USERS" = "HKU:"
            "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG" = "HKCC:"
        }
        [system.boolean]$isfolder=$false
        $addedpath=@()
    }
    Process {
        switch (test-path $path -pathtype container)
        {
            $true {$files=(get-childitem -path $path -recurse -force -file -filter "*.reg").fullname;$isfolder=$true}
            $false {if($path.endswith(".reg")){$files=$path}}
        }
        foreach($File in $Files) {
            $Commands = @()
            [string]$text=$nul
            $FileContent = Get-Content $File | Where-Object {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)} | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
            $joinedlines = @()
            for ($i=0;$i -lt $FileContent.count;$i++){
                if ($FileContent[$i].EndsWith("\")) {
                    $text=$text+($FileContent[$i] -replace "\\").trim()
                } else {
                    $joinedlines+=$text+$FileContent[$i]
                    [string]$text=$nul
                }
            }

            foreach ($joinedline in $joinedlines) {
                if ($joinedline -match '\[' -and $joinedline -match '\]' -and $joinedline -match 'HKEY') {
                    $key=$joinedline -replace '\[|\]'
                    switch ($key.StartsWith("-HKEY"))
                    {
                        $true {
                            $key=$key.substring(1,$key.length-1)
                            $hivename = $key.split('\')[0]
                            $key = "`"" + ($key -replace $hivename,$hive.$hivename) + "`""
                            $Commands += 'Remove-Item -Path {0} -Force -Recurse' -f $key
                        }
                        $false {
                            $hivename = $key.split('\')[0]
                            $key = "`"" + ($key -replace $hivename,$hive.$hivename) + "`""
                            if ($addedpath -notcontains $key) {
                                $Commands += 'New-Item -Path {0} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null'-f $key
                                $addedpath+=$key
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                elseif ($joinedline -match "`"([^`"=]+)`"=") {
                    [System.Boolean]$delete=$false
                    $name=($joinedline | select-string -pattern "`"([^`"=]+)`"").matches.value | select-object -first 1
                    switch ($joinedline)
                    {
                        {$joinedline -match "=-"} {$commands+=$Commands += 'Remove-ItemProperty -Path {0} -Name {1} -Force' -f $key, $Name;$delete=$true}
                        {$joinedline -match '"="'} {
                            $type="string"
                            $value=$joinedline -replace "`"([^`"=]+)`"="
                        }
                        {$joinedline -match "dword"} {
                            $type="dword"
                            $value=$joinedline -replace "`"([^`"=]+)`"=dword:"
                            $value="0x"+$value
                        }
                        {$joinedline -match "qword"} {
                            $type="qword"
                            $value=$joinedline -replace "`"([^`"=]+)`"=qword:"
                            $value="0x"+$value
                        }
                        {$joinedline -match "hex(\([2,7,b]\))?:"} {
                            $value=($joinedline -replace "`"[^`"=]+`"=hex(\([2,7,b]\))?:").split(",")
                            $hextype=($joinedline | select-string -pattern "hex(\([2,7,b]\))?").matches.value
                            switch ($hextype)
                            {
                                {$hextype -eq 'hex(2)' -or $hextype -eq 'hex(7)'} {
                                    $value=for ($i=0;$i -lt $value.count;$i+=2) {
                                        switch ($hextype)
                                        {
                                            'hex(2)' {if ($value[$i] -ne '00') {[string][char][int]('0x'+$value[$i])}}
                                            'hex(7)' {if ($value[$i] -ne '00') {[string][char][int]('0x'+$value[$i])} else {"\0"}}
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $value=$value -join ""
                                    switch ($hextype)
                                    {
                                        'hex(2)' {$type="expandstring"}
                                        'hex(7)' {$type="multistring"}
                                    }
                                }
                                'hex(b)' {
                                    $type="qword"
                                    $value=for ($i=$value.count-1;$i -ge 0;$i--) {$value[$i]}
                                    $value='0x'+($value -join "").trimstart('0')
                                }
                                'hex' {
                                    $type="binary"
                                    $value='0x'+($value -join "")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($delete -eq $false) {$commands+='Set-ItemProperty -Path {0} -Name {1} -Type {2} -Value {3}' -f $key, $name, $type, $value}
                }
                elseif ($joinedline -match "@=") {
                    $name='"(Default)"';$type='string';$value=$joinedline -replace '@='
                    $commands+='Set-ItemProperty -Path {0} -Name {1} -Type {2} -Value {3}' -f $key, $name, $type, $value
                }
            
            }
            $parent=split-path $file -parent
            $filename=[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
            $Commands | out-file -path "${parent}\${filename}_reg.ps1" -encoding $encoding
        }
        if ($isfolder -eq $true) {
            $allcommands=(get-childitem -path $path -recurse -force -file -filter "*_reg.ps1").fullname | where-object {$_ -notmatch "allcommands_reg"} | foreach-object {get-content $_}
            $allcommands | out-file -path "${path}\allcommands_reg.ps1" -encoding $encoding
        }
    }
}
$path = Read-Host "input path"
reg2ps1 $path
```

This is the final version, based on my previous script and the script provided by SimonS.
The script is truly complete, all bugs fixed, it can correctly parse all 6 registry value types: `REG_SZ`, `REG_DWORD`, `REG_QWORD`, `REG_BINARY`, `REG_MULTI_SZ` and `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, converts each `[HKEY_*` line to a `New-Item` line, each `[-HKEY_*` to a `Remove-Item` line, each `"([^"=]+)"=-` line to a `Remove-ItemProperty` line, and each `"([^"=]+)"=` line to an appropriate `Set-ItemProperty` line based on the property type. It accepts an inputted path, automatically detect whether the path points to a file or a folder, if a file with extension of .reg, it outputs converted commands to a file at the parent folder of the file with `${filename}_reg.ps1` as its filename; If a folder, converts all .reg files inside that folder, and outputs a `${filename}_reg.ps1` file for each .reg file to that folder, and then put all `_reg.ps1` commands into one `allcommands.ps1` in the folder.

I made numerous tests and have confirmed it is really really working. The script is now complete. I made major improvements, used better formats, and simplified the code greatly, used better logics and made many other enhancements.

This is truly complete, to use my final version, copy paste the function into an opened powershell window, and invoke it like reg2ps1 "full\path\to\content"
or save it as a .ps1 file and run it by cd $scriptdir and .\reg2ps1.ps1,
then input full\path\to\content, notice you shouldn't use any quotes, or the path can't be found...

---

### ***Update***

I made a mistake in the code, by specifying the `-Force` parameter when using `New-Item`, if the item already exists, it will re-create the item, emptying the item in the process, this is not what I intended, now it's fixed. By removing `-Force` parameter in the `New-Item` line, trying to create an item that already exists will generate an error that tells the item exists, and will not reset the item. The error message is hidden by `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. If the item doesn't exist, it will be created, the item will be empty, the process will prompt a message that tells the item is created, the message is hidden by  `| Out-Null`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a godsend

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty good, but you have some errors in your conversion code.

1. In reg value text that contains escape characters like "cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"" your conversion doesn't replace " with `" or similar.
2. You need New-ItemProperty rather than Set-ItemProperty when using -Type property.
3. PowerShell cannot work with "HKCR:" etc. without setting a drive first.
4. Out-File path parameter is -FilePath

Probably worth fixing

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.3), there is no `-path` parameter in the syntax of `Out-File` command on line 125, so you need to replace it with the correct one `-FilePath`:

Change this line:

```
$Commands | Out-File -Path "${parent}\${filename}_reg.ps1" -encoding $encoding
```

To:

```
$Commands | Out-File -FilePath "${parent}\${filename}_reg.ps1" -encoding $encoding
```

Also, you might want to check your code with these sample registry entries before publishing your "Final version":

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyNewKey]
"Value01"=dword:00000a00
"Value02"=hex:c4,ff,cc,ff,00,00,00,00,e2,ff,bb,ff,00,00,09,00,01,00,03,00,27,00,\
  55,00,2e,00,e7,03,00,00,03,00,00,00,03,00,c4,00,00,00,30,00,00,00
"Value03"="@tzres.dll,-243"
"Value04"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"Value05"=dword:ffffff2e
  
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyNewKey]
"Value06"="1445855232"

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\MyNewKey]
"Value07"=dword:00000000
```

It will be a good idea to test the code performance with these cases. I have found many errors on converting...

[The error codes appear when try to run test_reg.ps1 file which converted from test.reg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmlz0.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually this is not a bug of my program. I have tested your example and it works fine on both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7. I tested on 64 bit Windows 10 though, and I haven't bothered to test it on 32 bit older Windows virtual machines, so I can't ascertain the cause of the error. So either you used an older version of Windows or a 32 bit Windows or both, and according to the error, it seems extremely likely you are using a 32-bit Windows. The error is not caused by a bug in my program but rather your system's limitation. Does it work when you double click the registry file?

Comment: I have tried to convert that sample reg code on Windows 10x64 Version 22H2 (10.0.19045.2364) and in Windows PowerShell by using your code which I faced on those red error messages. How might your test result be good!

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος For your convenience for investigation, I share the content of the converted ps1 here: [https://paste.ee/d/gaEoo](https://paste.ee/d/gaEoo)

Answer (score 0):

https://reg2ps.azurewebsites.net/ has an input form where the user can enter `.reg` code and outputs `.ps1` code.